# How to show tooltip text in gridview row on mouseover?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, tooltip, mousehover

I need to show tooltip on mousehover of gridview row. I have checkboxes as template field. when the checkbox is disabled I want to show this tooltip.
Below is the gridview rowdataboud

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string State = (e.Row.Cells[a].Text).ToString();
                foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
                {
                    if (State == "Y")
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "alert('This data is reserved');");

                    }
                }
            }
```

Here instead of showing alert box I want to show tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting title attribute as:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("title", "This data is reserved");
```

This will show default style tooltip when mouse is over row, however, you may would like to consider [jQuery UI tooltip plugin](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

You only require to initialize it with the element for which you wanted to use the plugin, for example, below code will initialize and configure Tooltip plugin for entire document:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).tooltip();
    });
</script>
```